# How to mock POST parameters and Model attributes?

Tags: spring, testing, model-view-controller, junit

I'm using Spring MVC Framework and I want to test my Controllers with JUnit. How should I mock POST or GET parameters of a Controller and how will I access the Model's attributes to check its content? My Controller's signature is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findings", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String findUsers(@RequestParam("userInput") String userInput, Model m)
```

Comment: Are you using `spring-test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spring-test` and `mockito` alongside `junit` to accomplish the task.

`spring-test` enables you to test controllers and a whole bunch of other things in spring

`mockito` is a great library for creating mocked classes

This is a very high level overview of unit testing a controller. This may not be correct for your situation, but should give you a bit of a starting point.

```
public class SomeControllerTest {
    private SomeController controller;

    @Mock
    private View view;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setSingleView(view)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Model m = new Model();

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/findings")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m)))
        .andExpect(status().isOK())
        .andReturn();
    }
}
```

Comment: How will I access the Model's attribute to check if its content is the expected?

Comment: You mean how do you check the response of the controller?

Comment: I want to see if the value of the Model's attribute is proper. This value is about to be displayed on a .jsp page so I want to test if it works right

Comment: If I look at your method the Model is passed in, what would change that value? The result of your controller is a string, normally you would check that the value of the string matches what you expect given a specific Model

Answer (score 0):

For doing that I would recomend you a simple test where you instanciate your Controller (you can mock all the dependencies) and after that you call your method pasing Model.

```
public class MyController (){
  MyDependencyOne one;

  MyDependencyTwo two ;

  @Autowired
  public MyController (MyDependencyOne one, MyDependencyTwo two){
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
  }
  public String findUsers(@RequestParam("userInput") String userInput, Model 
  m){
      // do whatever
  }
}

public class MyControllerTest (){

  @Test
  public void myTest(){
      //MOCK your dependencies
      MyController controller = new MyController(one, two);
      Model model = new  ExtendedModelMap()
      controller.filter(model);
      assertEquals("yourAtribute", model.asMap().get("yourAtribute");
  }

}
```